# Curl working for Same Server File but not when calling another server

Tags: curl

Using Curl when i call same server hosted any website file than it working fine but its not getting any response or error message when calling another server hosted website file.

i'm calling simple curl by following script

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

        if (!curl_exec($ch)) {
        // if curl_exec() returned false and thus failed
        echo 'An error has occurred: ';
        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    }
    else {
        echo 'everything was successful';
    }

    $return = curl_exec($ch); curl_close ($ch);
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    return $return;

}
curl('https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
```

Above code not working when curl request url are Other Server file while it working fine when i call same host server file.

Comment: what are you trying to do on the remote server?

Comment: please look at my query i added code example there ..Thanks Alexandre

Comment: how did you fix it?